# Problem filtering by MONTH in ODATA Query in Get_Item step

Tags: odata, sharepoint-online, power-automate

We want to filter our *Get Items* step where the Month of the list column **ContractStartDate** is equal to the Month of Today.

So we tried this:

```
Month(ContractStartDate) eq Month(utcNow()) and Status eq 'Approved'
```

and we got the **Query is invalid** error on the *Get Items* step.

so we tried this:

```
month('ContractStartDate') eq month('utcNow()') and Status eq 'Approved'
```

but still no luck

The ContractStartDate is a DateTime field in the SharePoint list.

Comment: will it works if you replace Month(utcNow()) with 5?